# How to use Ruby gsub without breaking the replacement string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby

I work with Ruby 2.7 / Rails 5.2.

I use regex to validate data through postgreSQL requests. The regular expression is merged into the SQL request at execution time, using gsub, just before triggering the query:

```
query = 'select id, 
                case 
                when birth_date !~ '&validation_regex&'
                then 1 
                else 0 
                end as flag 
         from users'
sql_statement = query.gsub('&validation_regex&', date_val)
```

Where **date_val** is the regular expression:

```
'^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$')
```

I expect the regular expression to be simply copy-pasted in place of the &validation_regex&. But the resulting regex is different:

```
'^(?:(?:31(\\/|-|\\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))|(?:(?:29|30)(\\/|-|\\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\\d)?\\d{2})$|^(?:29(\\/|-|\\.)0?2(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\\d|2[0-8])(\\/|-|\\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\\d)?\\d{2})$'
```

All character strings such as `\1, \2, \3` ... have been removed from the regex.
When executed in the console, they are replaced by `\u0001, \u0002, \u0004` ... Validation does not work anymore!

Is this a standard behaviour of gsub?!?

How can I workaround this issue?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Note that `date_val` is simply a string that happens to resemble a regex.  While it is single quoted (so, e.g, `'\1'` in the string is a backslash followed by a one) what you show as the replacement presumably is a double-quoted (not single-quoted) string.  Note `')'` should be removed from the end of `date_val` and you refer to `&date_regex&` but in your example it is `'&validation_regex&'`. I have no idea why `'\1'` (`"\\1"`), and so on, would be removed.

Comment: Note that if [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) has two arguments the second one is a string or a hash.

Comment: Need more details because it's hard to understand what is you final goal. What issue do you try to resolve? Your `query` variable looks invalid. Why `date_val` is regexp?

Answer (score 0):

From the doc:

If replacement is a String it will be substituted for the matched text. It may contain back-references to the pattern's capture groups of the form \d, where d is a group number, or \k, where n is a group name. If it is a double-quoted string, both back-references must be preceded by an additional backslash. However, within replacement the special match variables, such as $&, will not refer to the current match.

To avoid that:

```
class String
    def greplace(what, by)
        s = self.dup
        i = 0
        while (i = s.index(what,i))
            s[i,what.length] = by
            i += by.length
        end
        s
    end
end
```

I agree, it's weird to not have a native gsub method in Ruby that do not interpolate the replacement string.

Comment: What happens using this method if you call `"aaa".greplace("a", "a")`?

Comment: You're right Chris. Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

I finally avoided unsing gsub, and directly replaced the **&validation_regex&** parameter with the **date_val** regular expression in the following way:

```
query["&validation_regex&"] = date_val
```

I found this trick here: [Changing a Section of a String](https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_String_Replacement,_Substitution_and_Insertion)

Ruby String basics!